# Calculating Web Server RAM needs

Tags: apache-2.2

Is the best way to calculate web server RAM needs this way:

- Apache processes max * average amount of memory per php script request (10-15 MB in my case)

So if the max apache processes is 40 and the average amount of ram each script uses is 15 then I would need at least 600MB of ram for just apache.

Is this the right way of going about it?

Comment: what do you mean by "script"? apache-mpm with mod_php?

Comment: php script...unsure of how it is installed

Comment: Well, you have to add "shared memory" to your calculations which dramatically changes your totals. also mpm-worker & prefork uses different amounts of memory plus your php version & php script with apc/zend opcache or various. so it's really too difficult to calculate early before setting up the server. Frankly there are many variables and many scenarios.  i would like to give you real statistics from a server work with real load. but no luck. but an extremely simplified (probably wrong) summary is if you have 100 rps / you need at least 8 GB with apache mpm worker mod_php 5.5.

Comment: I've found a nice optimisation post here which can give you idea about resource utilisation & memory consumption for a drupal blog http://2bits.com/articles/apache-fcgid-acceptable-performance-and-better-resource-utilization.html